# Simplest way to sync between the Jenkins build number and the maven build ID?

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration

our application maven version is `<version>my-version-SNAPSHOT</version>`. We use the maven generated version number to identify builds in all communications (bug descriptions etc.). E.g. a bug was detected in `my-version-20150908.142611-17`.

However, we don't know how to easily link between these IDs and the Jenkins build IDs. The same version is called in Jenkins `#54`.

The lame workaround we found out is looking in the Jenkins console output, look for the line where it uploads into our nexus repository, and find out which maven build ID corresponds to `#54`... As for the other way around - which Jenkins ID corresponds to a maven build ID - we just take a guess based on timestamps :S

Any better ideas - technological or methodological?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Description Setter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Description+Setter+Plugin) to parse the version number from the console output and set it as build description. The plugin's wiki page has an example that can easily be adapted to Maven.

If you are using Maven 3.2.1 or later, you can use the `${revision}` variable as part of your version number to pass a desired version into Maven, e.g. use `<version>1.0.0-${revision}</version>` and run Maven with `mvn verify -Drevision=${BUILD_NUMBER}`. See [MNG-5576](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5576) for details.